# issue with DataReceivedEventHandler trigger

Tags: c#, python-2.7, command-line, com, command-prompt

Hello Friends,
              I have below code which I use to run python script(using telnet,COM and USB) and capture the output. The issue that I am facing here is with DataReceivedEvent Handler which triggers after long delay about couple of minutes to get the output especially if there is COM connection in the script. Below is my code and I am not able to understand why it takes so long time to trigger and runs perfectly when I run it using command prompt.

```
          var start = new Process();
         start.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
        start.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", fileName,"")
        start.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        start.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
        start.Start();
        start.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Why does this happen to with COM? Can I use DataReceivedEventHandler for different protocols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated a bit further and confirmed that when capturing the output from a python script the response is delayed. However, by adding a call to sys.stdout.flush() I was able to get the desired behavior.